# Creative Exchange Live Gulp task returning not authenticated

Tags: sxa, creative-exchange, sxa-cli

We're using Creative Exchange Live gulp task to upload FE Assets but at the moment it is keep failing by giving 403 error status message.

I have followed the Sitecore documentation on setting up at this [link](https://doc.sitecore.com/developers/sxa/19/sitecore-experience-accelerator/en/modify-your-site-design-with-creative-exchange-live.html).

1. Enabled the file \App_Config\Include\z.Feature.Overrides and enable the z.SPE.Sync.Enabler.Gulp.config.disabled for overriding default config to enable MediaUpload, MediaDownload and RestfulV2.
2. Using sitecore\admin account as it defaults to Sitecore admin and checked if it's enable by checking config value for

```
  <sitecore>
    <powershell>
      <services>
        <restfulv2>
          <authorization>
            <add Permission="Allow" IdentityType="User" Identity="sitecore\username" />
          </authorization>
        </restfulv2>
    </powershell>
  </sitecore>
</configuration>
```

After that run the Gulp task and it gave us the error as below.
[image]

Anyone ever had this issue? If so how can I fix this issue?

Thanks.

Comment: Hi and welcome to Sitecore Community. Have you also modified ThemeRoot/gulp/config.js and set proper server url under server options section?

Comment: Also please add HTML of Answer with error message to your question in textual way so it's easily searcheable in Google. Image won't be

Comment: Hello @PeterProcházka, thanks for the advice, I will try to be more detailed and clear next time. As for the problem we have changed OOTB files a little bit and reduced the script smaller in size and included user and server configs in gulpfile.js itself. And the script gets user details either from variable in the file or if not gets from user input. Server URL is also setup properly and the request went to server url and get no authorization error for the FE assets and then since we have 5 try policy for the user it gets locked after 5th request.

Comment: Does it pass the username/pswd correctly ? Can you a run a wireshark trace to see that. Also, check if the username/pswd is correctly picked up from the serverconfig.json & config.js

Comment: Hello @AbhayDhar, yes it is passing user name and password correctly. Interestingly I have created support case to Sitecore and they ran the codebase in their test env to reproduce the issue, but all worked without issue. Now I am thinking something is happening in our local environment setup which is causing the issue. It's just bit painful to debug.

Comment: I guess you could try removing your node_modules and npm cache to test this again